# How to choose available drives except pendrive for backup operation?

Tags: batch-file

I made this script for my home computers to easy backup all my collection of photos and videos to one external hard drive.

```
SET BackUpDir=%~d0\BackUpDir

for %%d in (C:\ D:\) do (
    if exist %%d (
    robocopy %%d %BackUpDir% *.jpg *.jpeg *.dng *.nef *.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi *.3gp *.3g2 /MIN:20000 /MAX:2703622144 /s /W:15 /XD C:\$WINDOWS.~BT "C:\System Volume Information" C:\Windows "C:\Program Files" C:\Boot C:\MSOCache C:\Recovery "C:\Program Files (x86)" "C:\Documents and Settings" C:\ProgramData "C:\Users\All Users" C:\Users\Default "C:\Users\Default User" C:\Users\defaultuser0 C:\Users\Public )
)
exit 0
```

I have a few computers with different partition structures. One of them has only the drives `C:` and `D:`, but for example second one has five partitions.

Now I have this line of code with looking for files only on two partitions:

```
for %%d in (C:\ D:\) do (
```

I don't want to edit script every time to add additional partitions which don't exist for example on first computer, but do exist on second computer. I want my script to find automatically all available partitions on the computer except external hard drive from which backup script is executed.

How to change the command line above to make this happen?

I want something like this:

```
for %%d in ("list of all partition" except "backup external hard drive") do (
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already *know* how to get the drive you want to exclude, it's there in the first line, `%~d0`, since you're using it to set the directory you want to back up to.

In addition, you can use `exist` to find out which drives actually exist.

So the following script will process all drives that exists and that do not match the one where your script is running from:

```
@echo off
rem Expand following list as needed.
for %%d in (C D E F G H I J) do (
    if exist %%d:\. if not %%d:==%~d0 (
        echo Processing drive %%d
    )
)
```

When I run that from drive `C:` on my system, which has the `C:` drive, an empty `D:` DVD, and the `E:` SSD, I get:

```
Processing drive E
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this code:

```
@echo off
set "BackUpDir=%~d0\BackUpDir"
for /F "skip=1" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK where DriveType^=3 GET DeviceID') do (
    if /I not "%~d0" == "%%I" %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe %%I\ %BackUpDir% *.jpg *.jpeg *.dng *.nef *.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi *.3gp *.3g2 /MIN:20000 /MAX:2703622144 /s /W:15 /XD C:\$WINDOWS.~BT "C:\System Volume Information" C:\Windows "C:\Program Files" C:\Boot C:\MSOCache C:\Recovery "C:\Program Files (x86)" "C:\Documents and Settings" C:\ProgramData "C:\Users\All Users" C:\Users\Default "C:\Users\Default User" C:\Users\defaultuser0 C:\Users\Public
)
```

Windows Management Instrumentation Command **WMIC** is used to access information of [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk). The data of interest is drive letter with colon stored in property `DeviceID`.

All logical disks currently connected would be output with command line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID
```

The output is for example:

```
DeviceID  
C:        
D:        
E:        
F:        
Q:        
R:        
S:
```

There is a header line with `DeviceID` and next one line per logical disk. All lines have trailing spaces. The output text is UTF-16 Little Endian (two bytes per character) and not ANSI (one byte per character) encoded.

But interesting for the backup task are only the **local disks**. For that reason the command line is modified to:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET DeviceID,DriveType
```

The Unicode encoded output with trailing spaces is now for example:

```
DeviceID  DriveType  
C:        3          
D:        3          
E:        3          
F:        3          
Q:        5          
R:        5          
S:        2
```

Okay, drive letters are output with drive type information. The drives of type `3` are of interest for the backup operation according to Microsoft documentation for the **Win32_LogicalDisk** class.

It would be possible to filter the lines within **FOR** loop using an **IF** condition. But `wmic.exe` offers also a filter possibility using `where`. So it is possible to directly filter the list of drives by `wmic.exe` by using the command line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK where DriveType=3 GET DeviceID
```

The UTF-16 LE encoded output with trailing spaces is for example:

```
DeviceID  
C:        
D:        
E:        
F:
```

That is the output to process with a **FOR** loop as done by batch file code above.

**FOR** with option `/F` starts in this case a new command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between the two `'` inside the round brackets appended resulting with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` in executing:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK where DriveType=3 GET DeviceID
```

The equal sign `=` is not part of an argument string enclosed in double quotes. Therefore `cmd.exe` processing the batch file would interpret the character `=` as argument separator like a space or a tab or a comma and would replace `=` by a space character before executing command **FOR**. So the command line executed by separate command process started in background would be with `where DriveType 3` instead of `where DriveType=3` and that would be an invalid syntax for `where` clause. For that reason the equal sign must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character on parsing the entire **FOR** command line with its command block by `cmd.exe` before executing command **FOR**.

**FOR** captures everything output to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes the captured text line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** ignores always empty lines on processing the captured output.

**FOR** splits up by default each line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and assigns just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. That is exactly the line processing behavior needed here.

**FOR** ignores by default also all lines starting with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line option. The end of line option must not be changed here because the lines to process all start with a drive letter.

In real **FOR** first splits up the line using the specified or the default string delimiters and then checks if the first substring starts with the specified or default end of line character. So **FOR** would also ignore in this case a line starting for example with one or more leading spaces/tabs and next character is `;`. But that does not occur here and so default end of line option of **FOR** can be kept.

But first output line with `DeviceID` is not of interest. This line can be skipped on processing the captured output by **FOR** by using option `skip=1` enclosed in `"`.

The additional condition `if /I not "%~d0" == "%%I"` is most likely not really necessary on backup drive being a removable disk with drive type `2`. But it makes it possible to use this code also to backup all local drives except the backup drive to the backup drive which is also a local drive.